# Using CTE in where statement is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have a following SQL running in PostgreSQL v13.10:

```sql
WITH stuckable_statuses AS (
  SELECT status_id FROM status_descriptions
  WHERE (tags @> ARRAY['stuckable']::varchar[])
)

SELECT jobs.* FROM jobs
WHERE jobs.status = ANY(select status_id from stuckable_statuses)
```

And it is running really slow while replacing `ANY(select status_id from stuckable_statuses)` with array of ids ex. `(1,2,3)` is running really fast.

Here is the explain analyze for this query:

```
Gather  (cost=1005.64..5579003.45 rows=1563473 width=2518) (actual time=45.495..40138.515 rows=303 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=5.64..5421656.15 rows=651447 width=2518) (actual time=44.533..40126.793 rows=101 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (jobs.status = status_descriptions.status_id)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on jobs  (cost=0.00..5378777.15 rows=13571815 width=2518) (actual time=0.892..38662.091 rows=10537079 loops=3)
        ->  Hash  (cost=5.56..5.56 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.377..0.378 rows=11 loops=3)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              ->  Seq Scan on status_descriptions  (cost=0.00..5.56 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.310..0.370 rows=11 loops=3)
                    Filter: (tags @> '{stuckable}'::character varying[])
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 146
Planning Time: 0.711 ms
Execution Time: 40138.654 ms
```

Here is table definitions (taken form rails' `schema.rb`):

```rb
  create_table "jobs", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "filename"
    t.string "sandbox"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "provider_id"
    t.integer "lang_id"
    t.integer "profile_id"
    t.datetime "extra_date"
    t.datetime "main_date"
    t.datetime "performer_id"
    t.index ["provider_id", "status", "extra_date"], name: "jobs_on_media_provider_id__status__extra_date"
    t.index ["provider_id", "status", "main_date"], name: "jobs_on_media_provider_id_and_status_and_due_date"
    t.index ["profile_id", "status", "extra_date"], name: "index_jobs_on_profile_id__status__extra_date"
    t.index ["profile_id", "status", "main_date"], name: "index_transcription_jobs_on_profile_id_and_status_and_due_date"
    t.index ["status", "sandbox", "lang_id", "extra_date"], name: "index_jobs_on_status__sandbox__lang_id__extra_date"
    t.index ["status", "sandbox", "lang_id", "main_date"], name: "index_jobs_on_status_and_sandbox_and_lang_id_and_due_date"
    t.index ["performer_id", "status", "extra_date"], name: "index_jobs_on_performer_id__status__extra_date"
    t.index ["performer_id", "status", "main_date"], name: "index_jobs_on_performer_id_and_status_and_due_date"
  end

  create_table "status_descriptions", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "status_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "tags", array: true
    t.index ["status_id"], name: "index_status_descriptions_on_status_id"
  end
```

Comparing to same SQL with array I can see that it is not using index by jobs.status maybe because jobs table is really huge (~15kk rows) while status_descriptions is ~200 rows.

Could you please help me to optimize this SQL if it is possible.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Here is the query with hardcoded array:

```sql
SELECT jobs.* FROM transcription_jobs
WHERE jobs.status IN (2, 3, 4, 291, 290, 46, 142, 260, 6, 7, 270)
```

And here its explain analyze:

```
Index Scan using index_jobs_on_status__sandbox__lang_id__current_stage_due_date on jobs  (cost=0.56..98661.05 rows=26541 width=2518) (actual time=0.032..63.266 rows=483 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (status = ANY ('{2,3,4,291,290,46,142,260,6,7,270}'::integer[]))
Planning Time: 0.356 ms
Execution Time: 63.337 ms
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and index definitions as well as the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And, 15 million rows (15kk?) is a medium-sized table, well within the capabilities of your database software. Huge tables have billions of rows.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you! Updated question with table definitions.

Comment: If you just run the SELECT statement in the CTE then is it fast or slow? If it is slow then you know the issue is with the SELECT statement (and nothing to do with the use of CTEs) and you can focus your efforts on improving the performance of that SELECT statement

Comment: @NickW It is very fast I did `SELECT * FROM stuckable_statuses` and it took ~0.112ms to process.

Comment: But that's not the SQL statement being run in your CTE!

Comment: Is there an index on jobs.status? And why did you use an array? There is no (direct) relation between the content of the array in table status_descriptions and the status in jobs

Comment: @FrankHeikens There is `index_jobs_on_status__sandbox__lang_id__extra_date` index so postgres should use it and it actually uses it when I am switching from CTE to hardcoded array.

Comment: @NickW Sorry I do not understand, what do you mean by not SQL statement?

Comment: What happens when you use MATERIALIZED in your CTE? WITH stuckable_statuses AS MATERIALIZED (... See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: In your comment you said you ran "SELECT * FROM stuckable_statuses". In your question the SQL statement in your CTE is "SELECT status_id FROM status_descriptions
  WHERE (tags @> ARRAY['stuckable']::varchar[])". That WHERE clause is going to have a significant influence

Comment: @FrankHeikens It is even slower with materialized.

Comment: @NickW Ah, sorry, no I get what you mean. The CTE sql itself running for 0.1ms

Comment: The problem is in your data model, the array tags. When you have multiple values, you need multiple records in a relational database (like PostgreSQL). Arrays do exist and can be handy, but can also destroy performance because of the impact they have on the query plan. It's easy to pick the wrong plan, and that's what's happening here.

Comment: Just throwing out suggestions, no idea if they would make any difference (or why)... 1) Instead of using the CTE just replace what is currently in the ANY clause with the SELECT statement in your CTE 2) Try using IN instead of ANY

Comment: @FrankHeikens I actually tried to replace filtering by array to very simple `id IN (1,3,4)` inside CTE it also very slow.

Comment: @NickW Thank you for your suggestion, sir! I've actually tried it and the result is the same.

Comment: @jjanes Updated description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that it thinks it will find 1563473 rows but actually finds 303.  If there actually were 1563473 rows found, the hash join over the seq scan probably really would be faster than the ANY-driven index scan.

Unfortunately there probably isn't anything you can do about that with your current data model and the existing versions of PostgreSQL.  It looks like the stuckable statuses are substantially rarer in the jobs table than the non-stuckable ones, but the planner has no way to know that.

To force the faster plan, you could temporarily turn off either enable_hashjoin or enable_seqscan just before running this query.  That is definitely an ugly solution, but it should be a reliable one.  If you turn off parallel query (set max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0), that *might* be enough to switch the plan to the faster one.  If you don't get much benefit from parallel query anyway, then this would be a less ugly solution, but also less reliable.  Or, you could try to add [plan hints](http://pghintplan.osdn.jp/pg_hint_plan.html).

The most robust solution is probably just to run it as two queries, fetching the array/list of status_id in one, and then stuffing that array/list into the 2nd one.  That way the planner can actually see the values which are going to be used, and can plan accordingly.  (I notice that your hard-coded plan is still substantially misestimated, but not by nearly as much as the other one also not by enough to drive the plan choice.  This is likely a separate issue, unrelated to the one you currently face.)

For your data model, I'd intuit that the stickability of a given status is not something that would change very often, if ever.  If you could record that value directly as a new column in the jobs table and change it whenever the status itself changes, rather than needing to do indirection to a separate table, that would pretty much instantly solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation! I believe I will go with hardcoded ids, because I need this SQL for materialized view, so two separate SQLs are not the option here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql doesn't use indexes when executing `subquery` or `CTE` with `ANY()`.
Instead, you can use `inner join`:

```
WITH stuckable_statuses AS (
SELECT status_id FROM status_descriptions
  WHERE (tags @> ARRAY['stuckable']::varchar[])
)
SELECT jobs.* FROM jobs
INNER JOIN stuckable_statuses ON jobs.status = stuckable_statuses.status_id;
```

make sure you have index on `status_descriptions.status_id` and `jobs.status`. Indexes can greatly improve the performance for join operation.

Comment: @bgr11n does it make sence?

Comment: Just tried you solution and is also slow, sorry I can't attach analyze here. But I do not see that it is using index, but it is 100% there

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev It has no problem with using the index with the CTE/ANY.  It just thinks it will be slower.

Comment: The CTE is obsolete, no need for. Just use a plain simple JOIN and you get the same results. But that won't fix the issue in the data model, the usage of an array. And this is causing problems for the query planner